# pass complex type data from local storage to mvc controller

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

I want to send complex data from jquery to mvc controller,which is stored in local storage
In controller i am able to get no of record ,also getting categoryid value ,but taxyear data is null.

```
public class ReviewOrder
    {

        public long CategoryId { get; set; }
        public TaxYear taxyear { get; set; }

    }

  public ActionResult ReviewOrder(List<ReviewOrder> storedTaxyear)
        {

            CategoryPrice categoryPrice = new CategoryPrice();
            // IEnumerable<VMCategoryPriceDescription> ServicesCategoryList = categoryPrice.GetCategoryPriceDescription(CategoryID);
          //  List<ReviewOrder> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ReviewOrder>>(taxyearObj);
            return PartialView("_ReviewOrder");
        }

Jquery Code
  var taxyearObj = [];
            if (localStorage.taxyear) {
                var storedTaxyear = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("taxyear"));
                          debugger
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("ReviewOrder", "Tax" )',
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: "json",
                   traditional: true,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: ({storedTaxyear:storedTaxyear }),
                    success: function(result) {

                    }
                });
```

JSON Object

```
[
{
CategoryId :1,
taxyear: [{taxyearid:1,teaxyeardesc:lorepipsum}]

}]
```

Comment: It should be `data: storedTaxyear,`

Comment: Your json object is not valid for your model -`taxyear` is and array of objects but you model has `taxyear` as a single object. You need to change one or the other, and then use `data: Json.stringify({ storedTaxyear:storedTaxyear }),` and add `type: 'post'` (a GET does not have a body) and delete the pointless `traditional: true,`